# Is there a way to call a Java method from a javascript action inside a view in Notes?

Tags: javascript, java, lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I tried calling a Java method from within a Common JavaScript action within a view i created. The javascript itself works fine but as soon as i try to import my java package (as i do in xpages) or try to call the (static) method directly with the path in front my whole script stops working. Is there a way to call java from within javascript in an action or maybe some solution with LotusScript or formula language?
Keep in my mind that i´m not able to simply put my code into an agent and call it, because i have to pass parameters to my java method.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your java code in a Rest Service and call that from your csjs.
Depends on what you want to do..

Comment: that's a good idea. Thank you. In the mean time i resorted to writing the parameters into docs and reading them in the java method